Timeout waiting to lock artifact cache (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance
Every second project that I open in Android Studio will show LockTimeoutException. Already tried clearing .lock files and deleting ~/.gradle and they worked but temporarily. It's enough to switch to previous project and same error shows up.
Timeout waiting to lock jars (/Users/shalva/.gradle/caches/jars-9). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: 49901
Our PID: 50605
Owner Operation: 
Our operation: 
Lock file: /Users/shalva/.gradle/caches/jars-9/jars-9.lock

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.cache.LockTimeoutException: Timeout waiting to lock jars (/Users/shalva/.gradle/caches/jars-9). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: 49901
Our PID: 50605
Owner Operation: 
Our operation: 
Lock file: /Users/shalva/.gradle/caches/jars-9/jars-9.lock
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.timeoutException(DefaultFileLockManager.java:374)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:335)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:179)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:125)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.incrementLockCount(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.acquireFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:163)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator.onStartWork(DefaultCacheCoordinator.java:401)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator.useCache(DefaultCacheCoordinator.java:240)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:159)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:216)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer$ParallelTransformExecutor.transformAll(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:226)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.copyingTransform(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:112)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.copyingTransform(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.daemon.serialization.DaemonSidePayloadClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoaderForClassPath(DaemonSidePayloadClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.daemon.serialization.DaemonSidePayloadClassLoaderFactory.getClassLoaderFor(DaemonSidePayloadClassLoaderFactory.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry$ClassLoaderToDetailsTransformer.transform(DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry.java:181)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry$ClassLoaderToDetailsTransformer.transform(DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry.java:168)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.ClassLoaderCache.getClassLoader(ClassLoaderCache.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry.getClassLoader(DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry.java:103)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry.access$300(DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry$2.resolveClass(DefaultPayloadClassLoaderRegistry.java:96)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.WellKnownClassLoaderRegistry$2.resolveClass(WellKnownClassLoaderRegistry.java:91)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializerObjectInputStream.readClass(PayloadSerializerObjectInputStream.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializerObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(PayloadSerializerObjectInputStream.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:130)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:263)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:127)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecutor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SetupLoggingActionExecutor.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecutor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildprocess.execution.SetupLoggingActionExecutor.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.lambda$execute$0(ForwardClientInput.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.daemon.clientinput.ClientInputForwarder.forwardInput(ClientInputForwarder.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.lambda$runCommand$0(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:321)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)


BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s

Sometimes it fails with different error logs:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Cannot create service of type BuildSessionActionExecutor using method LauncherServices$ToolingBuildSessionScopeServices.createActionExecutor() as there is a problem with parameter #22 of type ValueSnapshotter.
   > Cannot create service of type ValueSnapshotter using method WorkerSharedBuildSessionScopeServices.createValueSnapshotter() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<ValueSnapshotterSerializerRegistry>.
      > Could not create service of type ResourceSnapshotterCacheService using GradleUserHomeServices.createResourceSnapshotterCacheService().
         > Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (/Users/shalva/.gradle/caches/8.10.1/fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
           Owner PID: 38542
           Our PID: 49669
           Owner Operation: 
           Our operation: 
           Lock file: /Users/shalva/.gradle/caches/8.10.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.initialization.exception.InitializationException: Gradle could not start your build.

